# Retrieve data form second tag occurrence in xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing xml file with simplified_scrapy library. I need to retrieve information from the second `<xref-list />`. However each entry in the file contains one or two `<xref-list />`, both of them referring to different information. If there are two `<xref-list />` I would like to retrieve information from the second, and if there only is one `<xref-list />` the I would like to retrieve information from this only one. How can I retrieve information only from the second one? I tried to specify the entire hierarchy but it does not work. I need to retrieve both `database=""` and `accession=""` properties for each object. I match database code with my database dictionary and I append the accession to the base url.

```
for ele in doc.selects('cell-line'):
key_values = {}
for k in ele:
    if k not in ['tag','html']:
        key_values[k]=ele[k]


    #Cross-reference
    database = ele.selects('Cellosaurus>cell-line>xref-list>xref>database()')
    accession = ele.selects('Cellosaurus>cell-line>xref-list>xref>accession()')
    cross_ref_dict = {database[i]: accession[i] for i in range(len(database))} 
    key_values['Cross-ref']=[database_dict.get(k) + cross_ref_dict.get(k) for k in 
               set(cross_ref_dict.keys()).intersection(set(database_dict.keys()))]

   database_dict = { 'CLO' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/clo/terms? 
  iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/',
             'EFO' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/',
             'ArrayExpress' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/',
             'ATCC' : 'https://www.atcc.org/Products/All/', # + .aspx
             'BioSample' : 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosample/?term=',
             'CCLE' : 'https://portals.broadinstitute.org/ccle/page?cell_line=',
             'Cell_Model_Passport' : 'https://cellmodelpassports.sanger.ac.uk/passports/',
             'ChEMBL-Cells' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/cell/inspect/',
             'ChEMBL-Targets' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/target/inspect/',
             'Cosmic' : 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/sample/overview?id=',
             'Cosmic-CLP' : 'https://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/sample/overview?id=',
             'dbMHC' : 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/gv/mhc/xslcgi.fcgi?cmd=subj&ID=',
             'ECACC' : 'https://www.phe-culturecollections.org.uk/products/celllines/generalcell/detail.jsp?refId=', #&collection=ecacc_g
             'DepMap' : 'https://depmap.org/portal/cell_line/',
             'GDSC' : 'https://www.cancerrxgene.org/translation/CellLine/',
             'GEO' : 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=',
             'IPD-IMGT/HLA' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/cgi-bin/imgt/hla/fetch_cell.cgi?',
             'IARC_TP53' : 'https://p53.iarc.fr/CellLines.aspx',
             'IGRhCellID' : 'http://igrcid.ibms.sinica.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cell_line_view.cgi?cl_name=',
             'IHW' : 'https://www.fredhutch.org/en/labs/clinical/projects/ihwg.html',
             'KCLB' : 'https://cellbank.snu.ac.kr/english/sub/catalog.php?page=detail&CatNo=59&strQ=', # + &submit1=Find+it
             'LiGeA' : 'http://hpc-bioinformatics.cineca.it/fusion/cell_line/',
             'LINCS_LDP' : 'http://lincsportal.ccs.miami.edu/cells/#/view/',
             'MMRRC' : 'https://www.mmrrc.org/catalog/getSDS.php?mmrrc_id=',
             'PharmacoDB' : 'https://pharmacodb.ca/cell_lines/',
             'PRIDE' : 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pride/archive/projects/',
             'RCB' : 'http://cellbank.brc.riken.jp/cell_bank/CellInfo/?cellNo=', # + &lang=En
             'Wikidata' : 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/',
             'test' : 'test'
             #'test2' : 'test2'
             }


 <Cellosaurus>
 <header>
 </header>
 <cell-line-list>
 <cell-line category="Factor-dependent cell line" created="2013-02-11" last_updated="2018-09-07" 
 entry_version="8">
  <accession-list>
    <accession type="primary">CVCL_K248</accession>
  </accession-list>
  <comment-list>
    <comment category="Transfected with">
      HGNC; 6554; LEPR
      <xref-list>
        <xref database="HGNC" category="Organism-specific databases" accession="6554">
          <property-list>
            <property name="gene/protein designation" value="LEPR"/>
          </property-list>
          <url><![CDATA[https://www.genenames.org/data/gene-symbol-report/#!/hgnc_id/HGNC:6554]]> 
          </url>
        </xref>
        </xref-list>
      </comment>
    <comment category="Characteristics"> IL3 dependent </comment>
  </comment-list>
  <species-list>
    <cv-term terminology="NCBI-Taxonomy" accession="10090">Mus musculus</cv-term>
  </species-list>>
  <reference-list>
    <reference resource-internal-ref="Patent=US7524937"/>
  </reference-list>
  <xref-list>
    <xref database="ATCC" category="Cell line collections" accession="CRL-12015">
      <property-list>
        <property name="Discontinued" value="true"/>
      </property-list>
    </xref>
    <xref database="Wikidata" category="Other" accession="Q54752994">
      <url><![CDATA[https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q54752994]]></url>
    </xref>
  </xref-list>
</cell-line>
</cell-line-list>
<Cellosaurus>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, simplified_scrapy doesn't support xpath, but lxml does. So if you pass the xml in your question (corrected, the final `<Cellosaurus>` needs a closing tag), to lxml, you can extract that information easily enough.

```
from lxml import etree
atcc = """[your xml, corrected]"""
doc = etree.XML(atcc)

for atr in doc.xpath('(//xref-list)[2]/xref[1]'):
        print(atr.attrib['database'])
        print(atr.attrib['accession'])
```

Output:

```
ATCC
CRL-12015
```

Comment: Thanks. But this only returns the first element from the second `xref-list`. `Wikidata` and `Q54752994` are still missing. How to retrieve multiple values?

Comment: Your question said " I need to retrieve both database="ATCC" and accession="CRL-12015". What you are asking now is a different question; maybe you should actually it as such and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did not explain it properly. I updated the problem description. I hope it makes more sense. Thanks